# InfluxDB - batch write multiple points with the same tag

Tags: influxdb, batch-insert

When I write multiple points with the same tag value, it only writes the first point to the database.
Is this a bug or must be different tag values when writing multiple points?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature, not a bug. You need to create unique points, otherwise non unique points are "deduplicated". See doc https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points

> A point is uniquely identified by the measurement name, tag set, and timestamp. If you submit a new point with the same measurement, tag set, and timestamp as an existing point, the field set becomes the union of the old field set and the new field set, where any ties go to the new field set. This is the intended behavior.